# TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting this error in the first function when i run the second one

```
function removeTime(date) {
      if( typeof date === "string" ) date = new Date(date);
      return new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate());
    }
function DailyPODashboard(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THIS).getSheetByName("Daily PO Dashboard");
  var date = new Date();
  var wn = Math.floor(WEEKNUMBER(date));
  var data = weekReview(wn);
  Logger.log(typeof data[4][17])
  for(var row=0; row<data.length; row++){
   
    var d1 = new Date();
    Utilities.sleep(100);
    var d2 = new Date();
    console.log(d1);
    console.log(d2);  
    console.log( d1.valueOf() === d2.valueOf() );
    
    data[row][17] = removeTime(data[row][17]);
    d1 = removeTime(d1);
    console.log(d1);
    console.log(data[row][17]);
    console.log(  );
    if(d1.valueOf() === data[row][17].valueOf()){
        Logger.log(" I'm in!")
          ss.getRange('B3:AA').setValue(data[row]);
      }
  }
```

where data includes big number of data and column 17 has the dates

been struggling with this for too long, so would really appreciate the help.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I was still given the same error and also i wasn't allowed to update my question so thought would ask it again better with everything given

Comment: Reasking the same question rarely ends well. The question is closed, but you are still allowed to edit it and once edited you have the option to consider it for reopening. But both the original and this question still lack a [mcve]. Without knowing what value `data[row][17]` holds, we can't tell you why this fails. Whatever it is, it likely isn't a `Date` object.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info , but  I included the value of data[row[[17] where a showed the column and logger.log it with a picture as well. That's not enough?

Comment: No, because we have no way of validating that that column is indeed the content of `data[row][17]`. And for those of us who know JavaScript well, but don't Google Sheets/Apps Script well enough, we also don't know in what format the date is stored. If would be more helpful if you could log `data[row][17]` and its datatype (`typeof data[row][17]`).

Comment: sorry for the inconvenient, I will edit my question.

Comment: Please provide the exact error you are receiving and if possible identify the line it is coming from

Comment: its exactly the same in the title

Comment: date is undefined.  Perhaps you meant Date() I can't tell because your code is incomplete and not reproducible.  Anyway Date() will work in that situation all thought I believe you should use new Date()

Comment: Im sorry for that. I just included a picture that has everything

Comment: I'm not interested in a picture of you code.  Just post the appropriate code.  That's all we ask.

Comment: We never get to see what `data[row][17]` is because your function fails before that.  After your Logger.log add `Logger.log("data[row][17] = "+data[row][17});`.  We have all been guessing what `data[row][17]` really is.

Comment: I already have done that in the second picture. Isn't that what you are asking for?

Comment: Well it's obvious  that your question is to much trouble to deal with I'm moving on to another question I voted to close this question.

Comment: In your previous image you logged `data[4][17]`. However, your loop never seem to pass the first iteration so `data[4]` is never reached by your loop. However, the fact that `data[4][17]` is a string, also makes it possible for `data[0][17]` to be a string. A string doesn't have a `.getFullYear()` method, hence you get the error. You'll need to convert the string to a date object first. Since we still don't know what the exact value is of `data[i][17]`, we can't really tell you how to do so.

Comment: To make a [mcve], you can put a `console.log('date in removeTime()', date)` at the first line of your `removeTime()` function. Then once you know the value of `date`, replace all your code simply that function and a single function call `removeTime(<The logged value>)`. If that still gives you the same error, you have your [mcve]. (And one that we can probably answer within seconds.)

Comment: I  agree with [Ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479156/ivar) sharing a reproducible example could grant a better idea of what's happening.